# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + 1/n}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + 1/n}}$$ converge? If yes, to where?

I searched this specific series but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I think that using asymptotic terms you have $1/n^{1+1/n} \sim 1/n$ that diverges

Comment: You might compare this to $1\over n\ln n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^n\ge n$ for $n\ge1$ is easy to show. Hence $2\ge n^{1/n}$, so

$${1\over n^{1+1/n}}\ge{1\over2n}$$

which implies $\sum{1\over n^{1+1/n}}\ge{1\over2}\sum{1\over n}$, which diverges.

Comment: Better invoke the comparison test instead of writing meaningless comparison to a divergent series. (Yes, I know what you mean, but OP might get screamed at by whoever does the grading. I would.)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: $\dfrac{1}{n^{1+1/n}} = \frac{1}{n} \exp(-\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)) > \frac{1}{n} \exp(-1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: u mad eshort work out of it (+1)

Comment: @tired: I presume that's a compliment but somehow I don't get it. What's an eshort?

Comment: u mad$\textbf{e}$  short work of it! ;)

Comment: @tired: Oh haha. It's a standard technique anyway, because whenever we have expressions of the form $a^b$ it is not so easy to observe its behaviour until you change it into $\exp(b\ln(a))$ where now you have a product instead.

Answer (score 0):

The series does not converge.

Consider whether $n^{\frac 1n}\ge k$ for some constant $k$.  If $k = e$, we have

$$\frac 1n\ln n\ge 1\to \ln n \ge n$$

But for all $n\ge 1, \ln n\lt n$, so we have an upper bound on $n^\frac 1n$ which means that the original sum is asymptotic to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the limit comparison theorem (more general form):

$$\frac{\frac1{n\sqrt[n]n}}{\frac1{n\log n}}=\frac{\log n}{\sqrt[n]n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

and then your series diverges since the other diverges.

For the other one: you can use Cauchy's Condensation test as the sequence is monotonic convergent to zero:

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log2^n}=\frac1{\log2}\frac1n$$

and the last one is just a constant multiple of the harmonic series.