# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{1+\frac 1 k}} $ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{1+\frac 1 k}} $

What I've tried:

$a = $ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{1+\frac 1 k}} $

$b = $ $\frac 1 k$

Limit comparison test:

$\lim_{n\to {\infty}} \frac a b = 1$

Therefore, by Limit comparison test, a and b diverge or converge together.

Because b diverges (p-series), a must also diverge.

Have I made any mistakes?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673312/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054911/42969

Comment: For $k\ge1$ $$\frac{1}{k^{1+1/k}}\ge \frac{1-\frac1k\log(k)}{k}=\frac1k - \frac{\log(k)}{k^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right indeed

$$\frac{\frac 1 {k^{1+\frac 1 k}}}{\frac1k}=\frac k {k^{1+\frac 1 k}}=\frac 1 {k^{\frac 1 k}}\to 1$$

and by limit comparison test we can conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Since $k^{1/k}\sim 1$, $k^{-1-1/k}\sim k^{-1}$ so the series diverges.